# counting props that aren't null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting named variables out of the props I'm getting passed. I need to know the number of props that are not set to `null`.
`Object.keys(this.props).length` counts all regardless.

I don't display the props that are `null` and need to change the layout for the previous props that are displayed based on the number of props that I will display.

I have a solution, but it's long and complicated (basically `if(prop) {numProp++;}`.

Comment: Did you try looping through them and counting?

Comment: Yes. that's basically the long and complicated solution I currently have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Array#filter()`to filter out keys with null values

```
Object.keys(this.props).filter(k => this.props[k] !== null).length
```